# logstash config test error missing binaries

Tags: logstash

I'm not sure why this happened, but I'm missing the binaries in my /opt/logstash. When I view that folder, it only has a folder vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/ which I think is the reason my logstash isn't even running on the port.

When I run

sudo service logstash configtest, I get:

```
/etc/init.d/logstash: 156: /etc/init.d/logstash: /opt/logstash/bin/logstash: not found
```

Something with my paths or java? I've tried googling, but nothing has worked yet. I can post my init.d also if that is useful

Comment: What version are you on? Have you upgraded lately?

Comment: I figured that part out actually just recently, I had my path wrong. Now I'm running into an error where something isn't connecting with my file beat, logstash and elasticsearch because my kibana is coming up empty